# Why names in builtins change binding of other names?

Tags: python

I thought names in Python were bound to objects. If this was the case, there would be an object `<built-in function open>` available, and at least two names bound to it, "`open`" and "`builtins.open`".
Changing the binding of one name shouldn't change neither the object nor other names.
Surprisingly, when I run the following, `builtins.open=0` also changes the binding of `open`:

```
>>> import builtins
>>> builtins.open=0
>>> open
0
```

**Why does this happen?**

On another topic, I've seen several questions asking for ways to implement pointer names in Python, such that a name would *point* to another name (instead of be bound to the other name's bound object) and one could change the binding of the first name by use of the second. For example, if the `->` operator was defined to bind a pointer:

```
>>> a = zip
>>> a
<class 'zip'>
>>> b -> a  # some way to point to a name?
>>> b = all  # this actually is changing the binding of a
>>> b
<built-in function all>
>>> a
<built-in function all>
```

If you think closer, that is exactly what is happening on the first example with the `builtins.open` and `open`, for some reason they are the same name.

**Could this be used to implement pointer-like behavior in Python? How?**

Comment: Every name in Python is a reference to an object. If you want to play with pointers, use a language meant for that, like C.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yes. I do use pointer languages too. I'm just exploring the boundaries of the Python language this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one binding involved here, `builtins.open`. There is no binding for `open` in your current global namespace; name resolution for a bare `open` succeeds because after failing to find a binding for `open` in the globals, Python tries `builtins.open` and finds it.

This cannot be used to implement pointers or pointer-like behavior.

Comment: That totally explains things. I guess my question then is: **can I add more namespaces to be searched if globals and builtins fail?**

Comment: @AndresR: Nope. Even things like `import *` don't do that, and there's a really strong case that `import *` should have been designed to do that.